# Miniube ingress is not fuction as expected. When I try to access localhost/foo it gives Cannot GET /foo

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, minikube, nginx-ingress

Here is the yaml file

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo-app
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: foo-app
      image: 'nodered/node-red'
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: foo
  ports:
    - port: 1880
---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bar-app
  labels:
    app: bar
spec:
  containers:
    - name: bar-app
      image: 'kicbase/echo-server:1.0'
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bar-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: bar
  ports:
    - port: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: foo-service
                port:
                  number: 1880
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /bar
            backend:
              service:
                name: bar-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
---
```

I use it with minikube. But everytime I try to access node-red from localhost/foo it returns Cannot GET /foo. Why is that happening?

I tried to change the ports but nothing worked the example from google worked as expected https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/. So the code I use for this yaml is almost the same as the own in the link but it doesn't work whatever I trie. Why? I use minikube on windows 11 home with docker.

Comment: Is the "bar" service required to demonstrate the issue, or can it be deleted as part of constructing a [mcve]?  What code is running in the "foo" container; is it actually listening on port 1880?